# Using values from SqlDataSource in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

After the `SQLDataSource` gets the values from the database, I want to be able to use these values in the code behind.  Kindly spare 5 minutes and give me some suggestions.

ASPX Markup:

```
<h2 id="pageHeader" runat="server"></h2>
            <div id="pageContent" runat="server">

            </div> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mkkConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PageHeader], [PageContent] FROM [PageKeeper] WHERE ([PageName] = @PageName)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="AboutUs" Name="PageName" 
                QueryStringField="Page" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Sub loadContent(ByVal _PageName As String)
pageHeader.InnerText= "How do i get the value from SQLDatasource ??"
pageContent.InnerHtml="How do i get the value from SQLDatasource ??"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your code behind:

```
DataView dview = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
```

And after, use the DataView to access the columns, if you wanna a a list:

```
For Each drow As DataRow In dview.Table.Rows 
    pageHeader.InnerText= CType(drow("PageHeader"), String)
Next drow
```

Or single:

```
pageHeader.InnerText= CType(dview.Table.Rows(0)("PageHeader"), String)
```

Comment: `Dim dv As DataView
            dv = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

            pageHeader.InnerText = CType(dv.Table.Rows(0)(3), String)
            pageContent.InnerHtml = CType(dv.Table.Rows(0)(4), String)`   This is what m trying now with your suggestion...but i get there is no row at position 0

Comment: You try putting the select arguments?

Comment: Doesn't using "select" make a second call to SQL?

Answer (score 2):

If you want that in C#, here's the code

First Don't forget

```
using System.Data;
```

Then In Event Code :

```
    DataView dview = (DataView) sdsBookInfo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string value = (String)dview.Table.Rows[0]["YourColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
DataView dv = (DataView)GetDataSource().Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

foreach (DataRow row in dv.Table.Rows)
{
    long id = Convert.ToInt64(row[0]);
    string name = row[1].toString();
    // ...
}
```